# why I cannot visit the api.openai.com

Tags: python, curl, openai-api

I create a plugin of openai in python, which can run on my windows with anaconda correctly and get the response from that:

but when I run this curl comman ,it throw out this issue :

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer sk-xxxxxxxx" \
  -d "{\\"model\\": \\"gpt-3.5-turbo\\", \\"messages\\": \[{\\"role\\": \\"user\\", \\"content\\": \\"Say this is a test!\\"}\], \\"temperature\\": 0.7}" \
   https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions
```

, it always throw out the

```
curl: (28) Failed to connect to api.openai.com port 443 after 21077 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

, does any one know why ,and how to make sure my anacond can visit the openai api?

why the curl command is failure

Comment: How about try use single quote `'` to data row? i.e. -d '{"model": ... }'